# Extending frozen dataclass and take all data from base class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Suppose we have a class coming from a library,

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Dog:
    name: str
    blabla : int
    # lot of parameters
    # ...
    whatever: InitVar[Sequence[str]]
```

I have a dog constructor coming from an external library.

```
pluto = dog_factory() # returns a Dog object
```

I would like this dog to have a new member, let's say '`bite`'.
Obviously `pluto['bite'] = True` will fail, since dataclass is frozen.

So my idea is to make a subclass from Dog and get all the data from the 'pluto' instance.

```
class AngryDog(Dog):
    # what will come here ?
```

Is there a way to avoid manually put all the class Dog parameters in **init** ?
Something like a copy constructor.

ideally:

```
class AngryDog(Dog):
    def __init__(self, dog, bite = True):
        copy_construct(dog)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use inheritance to solve your problem, you need to start off with writing a proper `AngryDog` subclass that you can use to build sane instances from.

The next step would be to add a `from_dog` [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), something like this maybe:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class AngryDog(Dog):
    bite: bool = True

    @classmethod
    def from_dog(cls, dog: Dog, **kwargs):
        return cls(**asdict(dog), **kwargs)
```

But following this pattern, you'll face a specific edge case, which you yourself already pointed out through the `whatever` parameter. When re-calling the `Dog` constructor, any `InitVar` will be missing in an `asdict` call, since they are not a proper member of the class. In fact, anything that takes place in a dataclass' `__post_init__`, which is where `InitVars` go, might lead to bugs or unexpected behavior.

If it's only minor stuff like filtering or deleting known parameters from the `cls` call and the parent class is not expected to change, you can just try to handle it in `from_dog`. But there is conceptually no way to provide a general solution for this kind of `from_instance` problem.

---

[Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) would work bug-free from a data-integrity perspective, but might be unidiomatic or clunky given the exact matter at hand. Such a dog-extension wouldn't be usable in-place of a proper dog-instance, but we could duck-type it into the right shape in case it's necessary:

```py
class AngryDogExtension:
    def __init__(self, dog, bite=True):
        self.dog = dog
        self.bite = bite

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        """Will make instances of this class bark like a dog."""
        return getattr(self.dog, item)
```

Usage:

```py
# starting with a basic dog instance
>>> dog = Dog(name='pluto', blabla=1, whatever=['a', 'b'])

>>> dog_e = AngryDogExtension(d)
>>> dog_e.bite  # no surprise here, just a regular member
True
>>> dog_e.name  # this class proxies its dog member, so no need to run `dog_e.dog.name` 
pluto
```

But ultimately, the point remains that `isinstance(dog_e, Dog)` will return `False`. If you're committed to make that call return `True`, there is some advanced trickery to help you out, and make anyone who inherits your code hate you:

```py
class AngryDogDoppelganger(Dog):
    def __init__(self, bite, **kwargs):
        if "__dog" in kwargs:
            object.__setattr__(self, "__dog", kwargs["__dog"])
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, "__dog", Dog(**kwargs))
        object.__setattr__(self, "bite", bite)

    @classmethod
    def from_dog(cls, dog, bite=True):
        return cls(bite, __dog=dog)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        """Will make instances of this class bark like a dog.

        Can't use __getattr__, since it will see its own instance
        attributes. To have __dog work as a proxy, it needs to be
        checked before basic attribute lookup. 
        """
        try:
            return getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, "__dog"), name)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Usage:

```py
# starting with a basic dog instance
>>> dog = Dog(name='pluto', blabla=1, whatever=['a', 'b'])

# the doppelganger offers a from_instance method, as well as 
# a constructor that works as expected of a subclass
>>> angry_1 = AngryDogDoppelganger.from_dog(dog)
>>> angry_2 = AngryDogDoppelganger(name='pluto', blabla=1, whatever=['a', 'b'], bite=True)

# instances also bark like at dog, and now even think they're a dog
>>> angry_1.bite  # from subclass
True
>>> angry_1.name  # looks like inherited from parent class, is actually proxied from __dog
pluto
>>> isinstance(angry_1, Dog)  # 
True
```

Most of the dataclass-added methods, like `__repr__`, will be broken though, including plugging doppelganger instances in things like `dataclass.asdict` or even just `vars` - so use at own risk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I know that bit would work, my problem is that I have a library building a dog object, from that one I would like to spawn an AngryDoc, without having to manually construct all the attributes one by one.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll try to extend the answer a bit.

Comment: You're probably aware since you explicitly added it, but the `InitVar` makes subclassing tricky/impossible. It's just not there any more when you build a new instance from an old one. Have you considered [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)?

Comment: Yes I tried doing that and in that way I achieved the 'best' result, but I still have to unpack the 'Dog' instance when I need it. Did you have in mind something better ?

Comment: I wouldn't say "better", but I'm rewriting my answer to give some context.